# allow specific attributes in html tags online tool

Tags: html

I've been googling to find an online tool to strip specific attributes in an html tag, but I couldn't find something useful.
for example let's imagine that we have an input like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="some-name-1" class="form-control"/>
<input type="text" value="" name="some-name-2" class="form-control"/>
```

And I need to remove every `value` and `name` attributes in all tags, and convert it to:

```
<input type="radio" class="form-control"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
```

Is there anything you can recommend?

Comment: Can you use Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can do the following: https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/7g6hyj4f/8/

```
$('#remove').on('click', function(){
  $('input').attr('value', '').attr('name', '');
});
```

Comment: I can use javascript, but actually I need to convert my HTML code

Comment: What doe you mean?